# DRF - restore_object() invoked twice

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to access extra context in serializer and a.t. documentation I am doing it in views as:-

```
serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA, context={'group_id':group_id})
if serializer.is_valid():
       serializer.save()
       return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

now in serializer I have override `restore_object()` and I need to access extra context in `restore_object`. Why restore_object is called twice and my extra context is empty second time.
When I added print.

from `serializer.is_valid()`

context print is `{'group_id': u'1'}`

next time from return `Response(serializer.data ...`
its prints standard context

```
{u'view': <accounts.views.MutateGroupMember object at 0x108278810>, u'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x108285a90>, u'format': None}
```

Why `restore_object()` is called twice and why context gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information here to diagnose your problem.

Are you using the Browseable API? That causes a second invocation of is_valid on a serializer that you didn't manually instantiate, which causes restore_object to be called again, [here on github](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py#L457)

Comment: any ideas on how to work around this? It's unfortunate that posting from browseable UI produces different behavior than otherwise